# AngularJS ex.com/forum?id=1 to ex.com/#/forum?id=1

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, forum

So. I'm making a Forum, and I want to build it with using AngularJS.

**First off.**

Now, I've set up a connection to my database with:

```html
<?php 
session_start();
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","uf") or die ("ERROR! With connection!");


function sql($query){
 return mysql_query($query);
}
$sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name, forum_desc, forum_created FROM forum_tbl";
if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
 $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name, $f_desc, $f_created);
 $query->execute();
 $query->store_result();
 
}else{
 echo $db->error; 
}
?>
```

It's separated to 2 files, First being **db_connect.php** and second **core.php**

I've made the tables above, they have sample data.

How can I now make the f_id, f_name,.. to JSON encoded data? And use that JSON in my main.js file to use data.forumid?

I have made php to read the data from the database using:

```html
  <?php if($query->num_rows !==0):
            while($row = $query->fetch()):
   ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $f_id;?></td>
                <td><a href="#/HELPME"><?= $f_name;?></a></td>
                <td><?=  $f_desc;?></td>
                <td><?= $f_created;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

BUT I do NOT want to read the data like that. 
I would love to use ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.

I did this with....

```
<a ng-click="setRoute('forum')" href="#/forum/id=<?php echo $f_id;?>" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
```

And in my html is ofcourse the `ng-app="urheilu"`

```
var app = angular.module('urheilu', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
.when('/forum/id=:id', {
templateUrl: function(urlattr){
return 'app/components/forums/threadlist.php?id=' + urlattr.id + '';
    } 
})
});
```

Thats how I did my dynamic linking.

DONE.

-Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You should store the rows in an array and then use json_encode() to convert it to json:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = $row;    
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Prints out True:True.